# Injective object in the category of projective systems of $R$-modules.

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, injective-module, functors

I am trying to prove that the category of projective systems of $R$-modules indexed over a directed poset $I$ has enough injective objects.

As suggested in Jensen's book ("Les foncteurs dérivés de lim..."), given a projective system $\{M_i\}$ one should choose an injection $M_i \longrightarrow E_i$ with $E_i$ injective $R$-module, for any $i \in I$ and then set 
$F_i := \prod_{k \leq i} E_k$. The family $\{F_i:i \in I\}$ is a projective system of $R$-modules (with the natural projections) and has a monomorphism from the object $\{M_i\}$.

The problem is I am stuck in proving that the latter is indeed an injective object in the category of projective systems of $R$-modules. My attempt is the following. Let $\{N_i\} \longrightarrow \{L_i\}$ be a monomorphism of projective systems and $\{N_i\} \longrightarrow \{F_i\}$ be any morphism of projective systems. I need an extension $\{L_i\} \longrightarrow \{F_i\}$ of the latter.
Fix $i \in I$; for any $k \leq i$ we have maps $g_{ki}:N_i \longrightarrow F_i \longrightarrow E_k$ (the outer map is the natural projection onto the factor $E_k$), and $E_k$ is injective, whence a map $h_{ki}:L_i \longrightarrow E_k$ extending $g_{ki}$. By universal property of the product we obtain a map $h_i:N_i \longrightarrow F_i$ which extends $g_i:N_i \longrightarrow F_i$ (looking at the pair of commutative diagrams defining $h_{ki}$ and $h_i$). This is OK, but now one should prove that the collection of maps $\{h_i\}$ is a map of projective systems, which I tried to and doesn't seem to be true. In my attempt I get to the point where, for two indices $i \leq j$, I should prove that $L_j \longrightarrow L_i \longrightarrow E_k$ is a commutative triangle for all $k \leq i$ (in other words, $h_{kj}=h_{ki} \circ (L_j \longrightarrow L_i)$), which doesn't seem to be the case in general.
Also I noticed that I never used the fact that $\{N_i\} \longrightarrow \{L_i\}$ and $\{N_i\} \longrightarrow \{F_i\}$ are morphisms of projective systems.

Can anyone help me figure out the point?

Comment: Hint: your map $g_{ki}$ factors through $N_k\to L_k$, so when $k<i$ you can assume $h_{kk}$ has already been chosen; how does it have to relate to $h_{ik}$?

Comment: Sorry it's not clear to me. What does it mean for $g_{ki}$ to factor through $N_k \rightarrow L_k$? Could you please provide more details in all the passages? I already tried hard to prove this point, so I don't really need hints, but something clear. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is true, so don't take my word for it, but could it be that a projective system is injective if and only if its limit is also injective?

Comment: I don't know. I could try and prove it, but I would also like to know if my attempt is correct and, if so, where is the point I am missing.